# How to turn off black and white screen on respawn in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In **CS:GO**, when player respawns (and are invincible for a second), the screen is black and white for a while and fills with normal colors after. I like to play dynamic game modes such as DeathMatch or GunGame, that's why I'm dying a lot and often. This feature is kinda annoying and hurts my eyes because the screen is changing colors a lot.

I'm wondering, is there some configuration command to turn it off? I was googling around but wasn't able to find one. Also, in response to some comments, I'm sure there is such an effect on respawn in CS:GO because I watched some streams on [twitch](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Counter-Strike%3A%20Global%20Offensive) and there is this thing everywhere, but it is not so noticeable because they are playing classic mode and die like once in few minutes. And there **is** a slight color fade on player respawn. **Here are some screenshots from the moment I was killed and respawned:**
[image: #1]
[image: #2]
[image: #3]
[image: #4]
[image: #5]
[image: #6]
[image: #7]

Comment: I'm playing CS:GO and haven't see this black and white anywhere. Did you check in the graphics/advanced settings?

Comment: a screenshot might help. But personally I think it's some problem with your graphics card/setting/drivers/etc. I've never had it

Comment: @Novarg, I've updated the post with some screenshots.

Comment: seems like it's the immunity time after respawn. So looks like it's set to 3 seconds on that server. There's a short discussion here: https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=223854

Comment: @Novarg, thanks, but I've already saw this thread.... I think... This won't work because these are server side commands, `mp_respawn_immunitytime 0` or `sm_cvar mp_respawn_immunitytime 0` will change server settings (for all players) and I have to have `cvar` admin rights for that server to use those commands... and it will not affect my client.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop this.  The most you can do is (as @DmytroTsiniavskyi said) `mp_respawn_immunitytime 0` but this will completely disable those few seconds of immunity when you respawn so you can easily get spawn killed.  I would not recomend this. And sadly, I could not find any plugin or clientside anything to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this exists as an indicator of spawn protection - that invulnerability period you get in all game modes upon spawning. It is most obvious in DM because of the instant respawn, but in classic modes it also occurs (just its usually not noticable because youre too busy in the buy menu)

There is no way to disable it and in all fairness it doesnt negatively affect the game.